# Mouse Speed and Sensitivity

Tags: mouse

I'm going insane trying to simply use an external mouse. This can't be as hard as it seems. The external Logitech mouse I am connecting to my MacBook Pro is way too freaking slow and I can't find any settings to improve it. I have tracking set to max and I did some terminal thing where I set scaling to 10 which helped if I move the mouse quickly but if I move it slowly it crawls slower than a freaking snail trapped in molasses. How can I get my mouse to just work normally where a couple inches crosses the screen at a steady rate no matter how fast I move it?

Comment: So you want to turn off [mouse acceleration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_mouse#Mouse_speed)?

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't already, go to Logitech support. Search for and download the support software for your *specific* model of mouse. Afterwards you should have a preference pane under System Preferences for Logitech which you can use to adjust the tracking speed of that peripheral.